# Cypress to test Radio Button Value

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, cypress

I am writing a cypress test for radio to check whether it is private or public.

HTML Section

```html
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="form-check form-check-inline mb-1">`  
    <input _ngcontent-c6="" class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="projectStatus" id="private" name="projectStatus" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="projectStatus" ng-reflect-form-control-name="projectStatus" ng-reflect-value="false" ng-reflect-model="false">
    <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="form-check-label" for="private">Private</label>
</div>
```

Cypress Test

```js
cy.get('#private').should('have.attr', 'checked', 'true') // Not working
cy.get('[type="radio"]').should('have.attr', 'ng-reflect-value', 'false') // Not Working
```

Part of the problem is when I console I see the message `<input#private.form-check-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid>` I could not find the attribute `ng-reflect-checked`

Anyone did cypress test for radio button made in Angular?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be a solution too:

```js
cy.get('for=["private"]')
    .parent()
    .find('input')
    .should('be.checked')
```

This way you don't need extra attributes to the input element.

Answer (score 3):

Well I added a value attribute in the input

```html
<input _ngcontent-c6="" class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="projectStatus" id="private" name="projectStatus" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="projectStatus" ng-reflect-form-control-name="projectStatus" ng-reflect-value="false" ng-reflect-model="false" **value="false"**>
```

The cypress code

```js
cy.get('#private').should('have.attr', 'value', 'false')
```

I hope  someone has a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It turned out to be the most useful command. I was struggling to figure out a way to cross-check an attribute value with cypress and this one worked!